# How to populate a dropdown from txt file saved in google drive

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I would like to populate the select list (dropdown) of my local HTML file with inputs from a text file
The .txt file is stored in my google drive which has values like this :

Option 1 
Option 2
Option 3
.
.

Is there any way I can do this with JavaScript within the local HTML that will fetch and read the file from my drive and lay out the contents as select options to the dropdown?

Comment: you need to use Google Drive API - which is some kind of a service provided by Google. That api helps you download the text file first, then you need to parse the content before being able to populate your page. For security reason, I think the text file should be read by your server. Then everything is just simple as usual.

Comment: This is very new to me. Could you please elaborate a bit on which API to use and  which format to parse the data  to? Just to reiterate, I am just trying to populate the values of a dropdown.

Comment: That's just the way I could think of. In fact I've never used Google Drive API before, you can try googling and researching about it. More exactly I've never written my own code to communicate with that API, but I've used a library of another one which helped me upload a file to my Google Drive using C#. I think you can search for such libraries (writing your own code requires more effort but of course may be more interesting).